# What kind of dimmer switch do I have?

Tags: lighting, dimmer-switch

Moved into a new place  recently and I don't know what kind of dimmer I have.

The dimmer switch: (*the whole thing is on/off and then there's an up button and down button; the blue led presumably corresponds to different settings but I don't know what*)

When I moved in the lights would flicker and hum (*I didn't systematically try the dimmer settings*). Soon after, the lights went out. The blue led on the switch itself wouldn't turn on either so I thought maybe it was a wiring thing but when i replaced one of the incandescent bulbs the bulb worked and the blue led worked again as well.

The light is steady and doesn't hum. Hitting the up/down settings makes the bulb flicker (*pulsing rapidly and hum*) in some positions. However, when I turn it off, it also pulses rapidly (*but not as bright*) and never goes off--at least for the couple of minutes I've tried to wait it out (*the blue led stays on on the switch too, but before it would be off if the light was off*).

[image: the switch]

[image: inside...there's three bulbs but thought a close up would be better. I don't know what the writing on the socket says.]

Comment: It sounds like you MAY have an old dimmer that is not rated, or made, for LED bulbs. OR possibly your bulb MAY not be a dimmable bulb.

Comment: Just wondering based on the size it looks big enough to be a old time fluorescent dimmer but The lamps are wrong for what I have installed.

Comment: Can you post different angles of the dimmer please? It's really hard to tell much about it in the photo you posted

Comment: the picture is out of focus, but i think that the lightbulb label says `not for use with dimmer`

Answer (score 3):

That dimmer switch looks a bit like a [Lutron Maestro](https://www.google.com/search?q=lutron%20maestro%20black&tbm=isch), but your best bet to find out for sure is to unscrew it from the wall and look at the back. (Don't forget to turn off the circuit breaker for that outlet first!)

However, as @jsotola noticed, a more significant issue is the light bulb:
[image: light bulb label: CAUTION not for use with dimmer]
"NOT FOR USE WITH DIMMERS"